# PhoneGap Facebook Plugin - Android - import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;

Tags: java, android, facebook, plugins, cordova

So the issue I'm having is with the Facebook Plugin for Phonegap.
(https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

I followed all the installation directions so I have the FacebookSDK referenced in my PhoneGap project and all.

I did create the folder within the src folder of my project directory to match the package name:

```
package org.apache.cordova.facebook;
```

There appears to be an issue with the package, it only has the p in package underlined with red.  The error is the following:

"The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Unfortunately within the ConnectPlugin.java it cannot import one of the apis needed:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
```

The error for this is the following:

"The import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin cannot be resolved"

I have spent time looking at other posts pertaining to this Facebook Plugin but nobody seems to have had any issues with this importing.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: After doing some further research it appears the Plugin class is no longer supported.  Is there any way to get the Facebook Plugin working still?